# How to maintain optional/non-optional keys using mapped types

Tags: javascript, typescript

So let's say I had this

```
interface Foo = {
  a: number,
  b?: number
}
```

I could do either make all the properties required
interface

`type Bar = { [Baz in keyof Foo]: Foo[Baz] }`

or make all the properties optional

`type Bar = { [Baz in keyof Foo]?: Foo[Baz] }`

but let's say I wanted to keep whether or not the property was optional or required in the mapped type, how would I do that?

Comment: Your first example already does this. In that example, `b` would still be optional. Furthermore, there is not a clean way to make all the properties of an interface required, see this issue about it: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13224